# How to move text fields or buttons or any content in a fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I want to know how to move any content like `edittext`, `button` etc on a `fragment`.

I searched a lot but what I found is how to move a `fragment` from left to right or right to left. I don't want to move `fragment`, I want to move content in `fragments`. 
When I press next `button` the `edittext` field I would like to move it to the right and then an other field appears.

All this should be done on a `fragment`. In a simple `activity` I did it with `animation` but in `fragment` I can't do the same effect.

Comment: why bold and why italic?

Comment: Are you working with Ms.Word ..Nice but my eyes @_@

Answer (score 0):

You can change any view's parent by following code :

To move a view from one fragment to another, first remove it from original parent :

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) yourChildView.getParent();     

if (parent != null) {
    // detach the child from parent or you get an exception if you try
    // to add it to another one
    parent.removeView(yourChildView);
}
```

Now add it to required fragment or View :

```
// you might have to update the layout parameters on your child
// for example if your child was attached to a RelativeLayout before
// and you add it to a LinearLayout now
// this seems very odd coming from iOS but iOS doesn't support layout
// management, so...
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(//required params);
yourChildView.setLayoutParams(params);

yourNewParent.addView(yourChildView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Animation should work inside fragment also. Use object animator to move the view components from one place to another.E.g

```
ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view,"translationX", 0, 750); // start , end position
objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
objectAnimator.start();
```